# PHP - Preserve instantiation of class throughout entire directory

Tags: php, sql, class

I am building just a small application as I learn PhP and SQL. Right now I am stuck on getting my instantiation of one of my classes to be preserved without having to keep instantiating it every time the page loads. I have two tables `Users` and `Representatives`. The login function finds out their table and logs them in and then creates a new instance of that class. When that class in constructed, it does a few things and redirects them to their proper module. It seems that I am able to instantiate the class, but the second I change to a new file, `$current_user` goes null. I don't want to have to keep reinstate it because eventually on the `__construct()` I want to store some user information as private variables, so I only want to instate `$current_user` once and use it throughout my whole project. Again, kind of new to this so I hope I worded this correct. Right now I just have the `Administrator` class built out (but I am only building for that table at the moment as I figure this problem out). Here is where my class and login function lives (this file is being `require_once()` on all my pages).

```
require_once('functions.php');
// Define Database Constants
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "root");
define("DB_NAME", "livelab");
if(empty($current_user)){
  $current_user;
}
function login_user($username, $password){
  global $current_user;
  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  $sql="SELECT 'Users' AS tableName, userId as id, username as username, password as password FROM Users WHERE username='{$username}' UNION SELECT 'Representatives' as tableName, repId as id, username as username, password as password FROM Representatives WHERE username='{$username}'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  if(!$user){
    header('Location:' . './index.php');
  }else{
    if($password == $user["password"]){
      mysqli_close($connection);
      switch($user["tableName"]) {
        case 'Users':
          $current_user = new Administrator();
          break;
        case 'Representatives':
          $current_user = new Representative();
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}

class Administrator{
  private $connection;
  private $user_table = 'Users';
  private $user_id = 2; // I have this as a set value for test purposes right now
  private $module = './mod-administrator/';
  private $current_cookie;

 //public vars
 public $test = "hello world";

  function __construct(){
    $this->open_connection();
    if(!session_id()) : session_start(); endif;
    $this->current_cookie = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, hash_password(uniqid()));
    setcookie('login_token', $this->current_cookie, time() + 60, "/");
    mysqli_query($this->connection, "UPDATE " . $this->user_table . " SET cookieHash='" . $this->current_cookie . "' WHERE userId='" . $this->user_id . "'");
    header('Location:' . $this->module);
  }
  // The function that opens our connection to our DB
   private function open_connection(){
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
      die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " ( " . mysqli_connect_errno()  . " ) ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Each *request* is independently handled; when you "change files" (i.e. load a *new URL*), all previous state is gone.

Comment: You can maintain data between requests in SESSION; if you have things like db connection resources in you class, these cant be maintained, and need to be re-established every request

Comment: or use a framework like Symfony and declare your class as a service.

Comment: a lot of this is hardcoded, you should rethink your hierarchy and use the Database to store as much information as possible. You could do this using just one User Object.

Comment: Ty everyone for their input. Still new to it so trying to find best practice!

Answer (score 2):

> Basic overview: You're currently using a more procedural programming approach to your Software which diminishes the ability to move your data fluently. I suggest taking a more Object orientated approach to this project and firstly designing something that represents a user.

**Database hierarchy:**

```
Users
    - User_Id (int) Primary Key
    - Username (varchar) Primary Key
    - Salt (varchar) Primary Key
    - Password (varchar)
    - Login_Key (varchar) Primary Key
    - Group_Id (int)
    - Ect...

Usergroups
    - Group_Id (int) Primary Key
    - Admin_Access (bool)
    - Ect...
```

**Program hierarchy:**

```
Object
    - Database
    - User
    - Group Enumeration
```

**An example of your infrastructure:**

```
class User
{
    public $Username;
    public $Email;
    public $Group;
    public function __construct($u,$e,$g = "Registered")
    {
        $this->Group = (new UserEnum($g))->GetValue();
        $this->Email = $e;
        $this->Username = $u;
    }
    public function GenerateUser()
    {
        // Connect to the Database
        // See if the user exist
        // Handle it and upload the user
    }
}

class UserEnum
{
    public function __construct($c)
    {
         private $Value;
         switch ( $c )
         {
             case "Admin": $this->Value = 1; break;
             case "Moderator": $this->Value = 2; break;
             default: $this->Value = 3; break;
         }
    }
    public function GetValue() { return $this->Value; }
}
```

**Usage could be something like:**

```
(new User($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['group']))->GenerateUser();
```

> Taking a more OOP approach to projects allows you to use the same data through-out your project without having to `define` or `global` mostly anything. Take for example a Person, every person has a name. Inside your Object, you can specify that the Object needs to have a name by giving it a property and then later use the Object as a Person. ie: `$People = array(new Person('Bob'), new Person('Jimmy'));` - This allows a more dynamic approach, you can pass the name through the constructor method and easily add more properties to the person without having to edit loads of code.

**EDIT: I'd suggest adding some sort of initialisation of your Software to determine whether a user is logged in or not, something like:**

```
// TODO: Create a Settings Object and Controls Object
session_start();
if ( !isset ( $_SESSION[$Settings->CookieName] ) ):
    $Settings->UserControls->CanPost = false;
    // Ect...
endif;
```

**EDIT: Also note that your directory set-up is important, that state should be loaded in the same way on every page ie, using the above initialisation file inside each file.**

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the state of an object, or any variable for that matter, you need to save it in the `$_SESSION` array. The values you store in there will be available through the entire session until the user logs out or the session times out.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['current_user'] = serialize($current_user);
```

You may have noticed `serialize`. To store objects in the session you need to serialize them, because they are complex data structures and not primitive values.

To access the previous state of the object you need to do the opposite:

```
session_start();
$current_user = unserialize($_SESSION['current_user']);
```

I would suggest to read some information about [sessions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) in the PHP documentation.

Comment: Values stored in session will be serialized/unserialized automatically